# reportlab string with TTfont how to get it's height?

Tags: python, reportlab

I am using reportlab to generate a pdf file. I has some problem when i draw a string on the pdf. how can i get the height of the string with TTFont?

the code:

```
# Register fonts.
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont('fz1', 'fz1.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont('fz3', 'fz3.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont('fz4', 'fz4.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont('fz5', 'fz5.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont('w5', 'w5.ttc'))

def draw_text(canvas, fontName, fontSize, x, y, text, cmyk_color=None):
    t = canvas.beginText(x * mm, y * mm)
    t.setFont(fontName, fontSize)

    if cmyk_color is None:
       cmyk_color = (0, 0, 0, COLOR_DIV_RATIO)

    canvas.setFillColorCMYK(cmyk_color[0] / COLOR_DIV_RATIO,
                            cmyk_color[1] / COLOR_DIV_RATIO,
                            cmyk_color[2] / COLOR_DIV_RATIO,
                            cmyk_color[3] / COLOR_DIV_RATIO)
    t.textLine(text)
    canvas.drawText(t)

c.drawImage('f1.jpg', 0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH * mm, CANVAS_HEIGHT * mm)
draw_text(c, 'fz1', 15, mm2pixel(5), mm2pixel(45), u'This is a string')
```

I can get the string's width by:

```
text_width = stringWidth(text, 'fz1', 15)
```

but, how can i get the string's height?

Comment: I believe this is what the font size means already (15 would probably be 15 points high), though I'm willing to guess there's more to it and don't recall all the details at the moment

Answer (score 5):

If you use a Paragraph then wrap it on the canvas, it will return to you the width and height that it will take up.

```
p = Paragraph(text, style=preferred_style)
width, height = p.wrapOn(self.canvas, aW, aH)
p.drawOn(self.canvas, x_pos, y_pos)
```

`aH = available Height`
`aW = available Width`

the `style` refers to a ParagraphStyle.

Answer (score 4):

Works perfectly ([source](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2003-April/001487.html)):

```py
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics

face = pdfmetrics.getFont(font).face
string_height = (face.ascent - face.descent) / 1000 * font_size

# canvas.setFont(font, font_size)
```